# Disable the stretching effect of axes in tikz for data smaller than ymax or xmax

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{animate}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,palindrome]{5}
  \multiframe{15}{ik=1+1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=0:25, 
      samples=100,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      xmin = 0, xmax = 25,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
      xtick=, ytick=data,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false
  ]
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!90,draw opacity=.6*(1-\ik/7.5)*(1-\ik/7.5)] {normal((12-4.75*\ik/15),(4-3.75*\ik/15))/(\ik/3.75)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, during the animation the axis stretches. I want to fix the axis (and the graph) to use a set coordinate system without deviating from it. So it will show e.g. the scope of x=[0,4] and y=[0,4], regardless of the intervals of the curve (in this case the curve has a variable height in the y-direction, causing the axis to stretch to compensate). Alternatively, a key, for instance `fix axes to set coordinate system` or something, is what I'm looking for.

Comment: This happens because you're hiding the `y` axis. You can correct the bounding box by adding a dummy node using `\node (dummy) at (rel axis cs:0,1) {};` just before `\end{axis}`.

Comment: @Jake Worked perfectly. :-) You can post it as an answer if you wish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you're hiding the `y` axis. You can correct the bounding box by adding a dummy node using `\node (dummy) at (rel axis cs:0,1) {};` just before `\end{axis}`.